# Installing "bluetooth-hci-socket" on raspberrypi v4.0?

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

Trying to connect BLE devices with nodejs on Raspberry PI. It needs `bluetooth-hci-socket` module as dependencey for `noble` module. Here is my error log.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/bluetooth $ npm install bluetooth-hci-socket
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EAI_AGAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bluetooth-hci-socket failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.

> usb@1.6.3 install /home/pi/bluetooth/node_modules/usb
> prebuild-install --verbose || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 5.3.6
prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ /home/pi/.npm/_prebuilds/e00ec3-usb-v1.6.3-node-v64-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/tessel/node-usb/releases/download/v1.6.3/usb-v1.6.3-node-v64-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN github.com github.com:443
/home/pi/.config/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: 5: /home/pi/.config/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js: not found

> bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1 install /home/pi/bluetooth/node_modules/bluetooth-hci-socket
> node-gyp rebuild

/home/pi/.config/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: 5: /home/pi/.config/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js: not found
npm WARN y@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN y@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: xpc-connection@0.1.4 (node_modules/xpc-connection):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for xpc-connection@0.1.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: usb@1.6.3 (node_modules/usb):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: usb@1.6.3 install: `prebuild-install --verbose || node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn ENOENT

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2020-11-28T07_32_21_944Z-debug.log
```

As per `bluetooth-hci-socket` documentation, I have installed all dependencies `node-gyp`,`python`,`g++`.

I suspect this is node version conflict. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Did anyone ever help you?  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing `@abandonware/noble` and `@abandonware/bluetooth-hci-socket` instead of `noble` and `bluetooth-hci-socket`

Comment: I had the same issue. Installed @abandonware/bluetooth-hci-socket instead and the installation runs fine. However, it does not seem to create any module in my node_modules folder, and the node.js script still comes out with an "cannot find module 'bluetooth-hci-socket'" Error. Any ideas of what I could do!?

Comment: @DianaVallverdu you may have to modify some `require` or `import` lines to require or import from `@abandonware/bluetooth-hci-socket` so that node searches for the right packages.  The files in your node_modules should be under `node_modules/@abandonware/bluetooth-hci-socket` IIRC.